# Access additional data in a n to m table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my App I have Users and Buildings and a user can be part of different buildings. I created a User, Buildings and a n to m table between them. Some Users, who belong to a building, can be an admin. So I added an admin field in the n to m table but how do I access it?

```
create_join_table :buildings, :users do |t|
  # users can belong to many buildings
  t.index [:building_id, :user_id]
  t.index [:user_id, :building_id]
  t.boolean :admin, default: false
end
```

I'd like to access the admin field, to see if the user has admin role or normal. E.g. `user.building.first.admin?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access a join table if you use `has_and_belongs_to_many`. Change the association to `has_many through` and create a separate `users_buildings` table, after it you can write in User model something like:

```
def admin?(building_id)
  users_buildings.find_by(building_id: building_id).admin
end
```

You can read more about HABTM and `has_many through` difference in [guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many)